# how do I push a view controller from a ViewCell in a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to use a UICollectionView and it's viewCell.  I have that going fine.  But on the viewcell form I have a button that I intend to have go to a settings view.  I'm trying to "push it onto the stack".  Xcode complains of "no visible interface for the selector".  Some code and the error message are below.

// TryColViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TryColViewContViewController.h"


@interface TryColViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outletNameLBL;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outletCellLabel;
@property (readwrite) NSInteger intTest;
@property (readwrite) TryColViewContViewController *theHost;




- (IBAction)actionPlus1:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)actionMinus1:(id)sender;


- (IBAction)actionNameEdit:(id)sender;
```

//  TryColViewCell.m

```
#import "TryColViewCell.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"


@implementation TryColViewCell {
@public    int intCellNumber;  //TODO: get this to track the row/cell #
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (IBAction)actionPlus1:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)actionMinus1:(id)sender {

}


- (IBAction)actionNameEdit:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Name Edit");



    SettingsViewController *viewControllerB =
        [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewControllerB.propName = _outletNameLBL.text;
    [self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
    [self.theHost  pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];


}
@end
```

// Error message on PushVIewController line

```
TryColViewCell.m:83:11: No visible @interface for 'TryColViewCell' 
declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated:'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the new view controller from the view controller that contains the collection view, not the cell. Only a subclass of `UIViewController` has the method `pushViewController:animated.` to override.

In your table view controller, do something like this, assuming you are using storyboard:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

  static NSString* identifier = @"Cell";
  CellSubClass *cell = 
       (CellSubClass*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

  [cell.upButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(actionPlus1:) 
       forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.downButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(actionMinus1:) 
       forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  ...
}
```

Comment: How do I trigger that from a button on the viewCell?

Comment: I am calling a subfunction of the hosting UICollectionViewController but it has the same error message.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, assign the correct handler to the button with `addTarget:selector:forControlEvent:`. The handler should be in the same view controller.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Also, I don't seem to be able to actually call that subfunction I spoke of.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify. It seems you lack some basic understanding on how view controllers and table view cells work. This problem is essentially a new question. (You should accept this one and ask another one.)